# Data source name not found and no default driver specified error caused by wrong TargetCPU setting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, odbc, adodb

This one was driving me crazy, but I found a hacky solution that I have not found anywhere else on the net.

The solution: Change your Target CPU to x86 to avoid the known ODBC problems with 32-bit/64-bit.

I do not know how to fix it so you can use AnyCPU or 64bit. For the time being I seem to be stuck with 32 bit as long as I am using ODBC. The weird thing is that the external library which runs the actual code is compiled using AnyCPU. But the consuming project needs to be in X86.

I am not going to mark this as an answer because there are too many outstanding questions.

Background on my particular problem to put things in context:

I had a project that used an external library which I built. This library still uses ADODB a lot. My project was doing weird things so I re-built it from scratch, keeping as many default settings as possible to help in debugging it.

Well, my ADODB.Connection.Open() function in the external library was failing with the above error. The old project worked fine. New project threw the error. The difference was the Target CPU.

I kept seeing references to 64bit vs 32bit DSNs, which I know all about (supposedly) but I was going DSN-less.

My external library is compiled to AnyCPU, and I have other projects using it also compiled in AnyCPU but I think I am not encountering the ADODB code in the other projects so never encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678723/applications-namespace-becomes-unavailable-as-an-object-datasource-after-switchi

It sounds like we're running into a similar issue, however I am not utilizing ODBC and AnyCPU seems to work for me. It's just x64 that has issues. I'll let you know if I find out anything

Answer (score 0):

ODBC using a COM type provider like OleDb aren't available because COM is only supported under 32bit mode.